# ECS with CDK. How to handle service deployments & update image tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk

I have an ECS stack that is stood up through CDK. TaskDefinitions/Services and all other built via CDK etc. However, our deployment process is via Jenkins and that is not using a CDK stack update to manage the deployment.

Right now Jenkins just pushes a new container image to ECR and makes a new TaskDefinition revision with the new image tag. As recommended by AWS we are not using "latest" as a tag but instead using the commitId and we have tag immutability turned on for our ECR repos.

So... The situation we end up in is that CDK ends up being out of sync in terms of imageTag. This is not a big deal, CDK is smart enough to ignore this for stack updates, however, if you make any other changes that would force CDK to make a new TaskDefinition revision then it will clobber the imageTag of the previous TD revision and your service will be busted.

So - is handling the deployment outside of CDK a fundamentally bad idea? Should Jenkins make a CDK update and deploy that? This seems slightly more cumbersome since we have deployments triggered all the time for different services.

Is there a better solution? Write some additional CDK code to have it check current TaskDef revision and insert the current imageTag? looking for ideas

--UPDATE

So I wrote a package to go grab the current image tag and drop that into the CDK task def construct - however - when I deploy my CDK stack this forces CDK to create a new revision for the Task Definition - even though there are no changes needed. This forces a service update - which i don't want. The behavior i am looking for is for this to stay in step with what has been deployed and basically do nothing unless some changes are made to other Task Def params. Any ideas? Do I need to do something with caching in runtime context?

Comment: "Is there a better solution? Write some additional CDK code to have it check current TaskDef revision and insert the current imageTag?" That is certainly what I would try.

Comment: @MarkB i tried this but it ends up just making a new Task Def revision every time you deploy the CDK stack even if the image tag is the same as what is used in the current task def..

Comment: I would think there is some difference in the task definition that is causing it to do that.